# Dependency JSON Formate In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I working with JSON dependency where i have to insert into database

Here is my PHP Code

```
    $data = [];
    foreach ($quantity as $key3 => $fname1) {
        $data['quantity'][] = $_POST['quantity'][$key3];
    }

    foreach ($flower_id as $key => $fname) {
        $data['flower_id'][] = $_POST['flower_id'][$key];
    }
    foreach ($flower_price as $key1 => $fname1) {
        $data['flower_price'][] = $_POST['flower_price'][$key1];
    }
    foreach ($customer_id as $key2 => $fname1) {
        $data['customers'][] = $_POST['customer_id'][$key2];
    }
  echo json_encode($data);
```

JSON response is

```
 {"quantity":["2","3"],"flower_id":["1"],"flower_price":["12"],"customers":["21","20"]}
```

This is single flower if its multiple

```
{"quantity":["13","2","12","3"],"flower_id":["1","2"],"flower_price":["12","22"],"customers":["21","20"]}
```

For each customer has two flowers and each flower has its price and its quantity as show in picture

[image]

But i need individual dependency array to insert into database.
like individual **customers dependent flower_id flower_price and quantity**
how to do with this

looks like

```
[{
    "customer_id": 20,
    "flower_id": 1,
    "flower_price": 12,
    "quantity": 3
},
{
    "customer_id": 21,
    "flower_id": 1,
    "flower_price": 12,
    "quantity": 2
}]
```

If you had any other alternative you can support

Please help me regarding this

Thank you

Comment: can you please share the result of `$_POST` before you run loop.

Comment: in the $_POST, do you always get one flower_id & flower_price? or can it be multiple?

Comment: it can be multiple only customers are constant, everything else can be more

Comment: here is the post

array(4) {
  ["flower_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["flower_price"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  ["customer_id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  ["quantity"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
}

Comment: Modified the question

Comment: When you send the data like this in the post its hard make a connection between selected flower & the customer. I suggest that you make the dataset from the javascript (containing customer relation) & send it to the backend. If you post your html & javascript code. I can post you a solution

Comment: function addGroupOrderForm() {
        var data = $("#grouporder-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseurl + "product/ajax_addOrderToGroup",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#grouporder-submit").html('Creating ...');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

Comment: add the html of "#grouporder-form" as well. so that I can get a clear idea to post a solution

Comment: its hard to copy html nothing  as shown in image in question
<input name=customer[]>
<input name=flower_id[]> so on...as usual

Comment: Now the problem is there on the html as I can see. is this form generating dynamically? or a static from. we might need to change some names of the <input>. without having a look at the html, it hard to give a exact solution. if you can add the html to a jsfiddle and post it here that would be better

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r6dtk30j/

Here is the Fiddle with html and javascript

Comment: @SpikyChathu
Check the  https://jsfiddle.net/r6dtk30j/2/  here for the html and javacript